# I want to count letters in individual words in a list and remove those words under 3 letter

Tags: python

I have a list of words that I am trying to break into a string and then remove any words in that string that are under 3 letters - but not really sure how to go about it
The list is ["John", "Peter", "A", "Be", "Tom", "June"]

Comment: I would start by iterating through the array, checking the length of each string in the array, if it is greater than 3 characters then append to a variable which will be your resulting string.

Comment: Consider looking into the `filter` (see [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/filter)) and `len` (see [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/len)) functions that are built in into python.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this. All 3 methods rely on `len()` to count how many items there are. Assume:

```
data = ["John", "Peter", "A", "Be", "Tom", "June"]
```

#### 1: traditional for loop

Iterate through the list and add the words more than length of 3 to the results list:

```
results = []
for item in data:
    if len(item) >= 3:
        results.append(item)
```

#### 2: list comprehension

This is a condensed version of method 1 and my favourite:

```
results = [item for item in data if len(item) >= 3]
```

#### 3: filter

This is my least favourite, but is still an option. It uses a function that returns True/False to check each item:

```
results = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 3, data))
```

You could also use a normal function instead of lambda here:

```
def more_than_three(item):
    return len(item) >= 3

results = list(filter(more_than_three, data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample Code:

```
Sample_List = ["John", "Peter", "A", "Be", "Tom", "June"]
Sample_List = [x for x in Sample_List if len(str(x)) > 3]
print(Sample_List)
```

Output:

```
['John', 'Peter', 'June']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=["John", "Peter", "A", "Be", "Tom", "June"]
for x in a:
    if len(x)<3:
        a.remove(x)
        print(a)
```